# Fastest or easy-to-use reverse-proxy for Windows

Tags: windows, networking, proxy

I need to proxying port `80` to `localhost:81` and to `virtualbox_guest:4567`.

Normally on Linux I use NginX, with this configuration:

```
user nobody;
worker_processes  auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 131072;
events {
    worker_connections 8192;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}
http {
    client_max_body_size 8M;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 90;
    keepalive_requests 16384;
    types_hash_max_size 8192;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    gzip on;
    gzip_buffers      16 8k;
    gzip_comp_level   4;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_min_length   1280;
    gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon image/bmp;
    gzip_vary         on;
    upstream aaa {
      server 127.0.0.1:81;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name aaa.localhost;
        root /home/aaa/www;
        access_log /home/aaa/nginx.access.log;
        error_log /home/kyz/Dropbox/go/src/PUKIS/logs/nginx.error.log;
        location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri @bbb;
        }
        location @pukis {
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   CLIENT_IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://aaa;
        }
    }
    upstream bbb {
      server 127.0.0.1:4567;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name bbb.localhost "" _;
        root /home/bbb/web;
        access_log /home/bbb/nginx.access.log;
        error_log /home/bbb/nginx.error.log;
        location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri @bbb;
        }
        location @debug {
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   CLIENT_IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://bbb;
        }
    }
}
```

What software should I use to do this on Windows?

**Note**: I know there is [nginx for Windows](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html), but there are some limitations.

Comment: So which limitations are relevant ? This will influence which solution we can offer.

Answer (score 1):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) will allow you to do this, in terms of the reverse proxying and header insertion.

there's a free license for 10 concurrent users, and we offer free support also.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik, who are the authors of WinGate.